# How to make a SELECT statement show more than 1000 records in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I would like to know How to display more than 1000 registers when I`m using a SELECT statement in MYSQL

Comment: What exactly are you doing/using that is imposing a 1000 row limit?

Comment: Hello @AlexK am using the following script: SELECT * FROM tableName. My main problem is that the table has 15,000 records and I would like to show at least 2000 records

Comment: This is more of a workbench problem than a logical / SQL problem. Refer to the settings how you can increase the output of the resultset which would fetch more rows as the resultset.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using MySQL Workbench...

Edit->Preferences, 
SQL Editor->SQL Execution
Uncheck "Limit Rows", or set "Limit Rows Count" higher

Comment: In MySQL Workbench 6.0, "Limit Rows" is in SQL Queries tab rather than SQL Editor tab.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration file for the [`--i-am-a-dummy`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates) option. You are not really a dummy but it keeps you from shooting yourself in the foot with things like long running queries.

Comment: According to the doc, `--i-am-a-dummy` concerns `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, not `SELECT`.